# Inserting columns with a case statement

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, case

I have an issue where I would like to look for statements in a single column and each time I find them insert a new column into the mix. Im using a mysql database.

For example say I have data like this

```
  Class     Sub
  -----------------
    1       math       
    1       tech 
    2       math
    2       english
    3       math
```

I would like the data to be output like this:

```
Class    math  tech english
---------------------------
    1      Y     Y     N
    2      Y     N     Y
    3      Y     N     N
```

I am trying to use `CASE` statements to find the values in the column, but the problem is that it will only return one result in the column for the value it finds, and i end up getting the same class repeated with a case statement for each column. Combining the case statements wont work as that still gives me a single column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap the `CASE` expression in an aggregate and add a  `GROUP BY`. In this case `MAX` will work as alphabetically `Y` comes after `N`

[(SQL Fiddle Demo)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/186ec/13)

```
SELECT class,
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN ( community_id = 'Math' ) THEN 'Y'
             ELSE 'N'
           END)  AS Math,
       MAX (CASE
              WHEN ( community_id = 'tech' ) THEN 'Y'
              ELSE 'N'
            END) AS tech,
       MAX (CASE
              WHEN ( community_id = 'english' ) THEN 'Y'
              ELSE 'N'
            END) AS english
FROM   x_class_community
GROUP  BY class
```

Comment: Using the max function and group by does not solve the issue that for each individual class i have i need all the values across represented. In my case when i do the group by function i lose the duplicates, which is fine, but the values are not represented across the single class.

Comment: @mmSQL - This returns the results you said you wanted from your example data ([see SQL Fiddle link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/186ec/10)). Are you saying that you actually wanted something different?

Comment: Werid... It seems using the word 'Checked' as a THEN value for the case statement causes it not to work. Any idea why?

Comment: @mmSQL - Can you show the exact syntax that causes the problem? Also how do you mean not work. It gives you an error message?

Comment: Here's an example using the link you sent me... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/186ec/15/0

Comment: If you want to use the word `checked` instead of `Y` use `MIN` instead as `checked` < `N`

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what the min and max function are for the case statement. Why do we need them to filter alphabetically?

Comment: @mmSQL - They are required because even though your example data has no more than one row per `class, sub` combination in general that might not be true. You could have multiple rows so you need to use an aggregate to tell it which value to show in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using `PIVOT` functionality. You haven't specified your DBMS, however here is a link for SQL Server: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server then you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select class,
  isnull(math, 'N') math, 
  isnull(tech, 'N') tech, 
  isnull(english, 'N') english
from
(
  SELECT class, community_id, 'Y' as flag
  FROM   x_class_community
) src
pivot
(
  max(flag)
  for community_id in (math, tech, english)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/186ec/6)

The result is:

```
| CLASS | MATH | TECH | ENGLISH |
---------------------------------
|     1 |    Y |    Y |       N |
|     2 |    Y |    N |       Y |
|     3 |    Y |    N |       N |
```